# Evaluation of jQuery function variable value during definition of that function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, color-picker

I have a large number of rows in a table within which I wish to attach a unique colorpicker (jQuery plugin) to each cell in a particular column identified by unique ids. Given this, I want to automate the generation of instances of the colorpicker as follows:

```
var myrows={"a","b","c",.....}
var mycolours={"ffffff","fcdfcd","123123"...}

for (var i=0;i<myrows.length;i++) {
    $("#"+myrows[i]+"colour").ColorPicker({flat: false,
    color: mycolours[i],
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) { 
        $("#"+myrows[i]+"currentcolour").css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        }
});
```

Now this doesn't work because the evaluation of the $("#"+myrows[i]+"currentcolour") component occurs at the time the function is *called*, not when it is defined (which is want I need).

Given that this plugin javascript appends its code to the  level and not to the underlying DOM component that I am accessing above so can't derive what id this pertains to, how can I evaluate the variable *during* function declaration/definition?

Thanks for any help/insight anyone can give.

Brian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$.each(myrows, function(i, row) {
  $("#"+row+"colour").ColorPicker({flat: false,
    color: mycolours[i],
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) { 
      $("#"+row+"currentcolour").css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
  });  
});
```

The [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function [creates a closure](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L537), so the variable you're passing in (`row`) is it's own copy scoped correctly for what you want here, instead of the `i` being what it was at the end of the `for()` loop and your function getting the last element of that array.